# How to lock a particular column using xlwt

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwt

I am trying to lock particular column using xlwt but not it is not working. I succeeded when trying to lock a particular cell when opting for `cell.write()` method. But since my data is in for loop and I want 1st, 2nd and 4th column's data to be locked and rest to be editable. Any suggestion, reference ?

Comment: Can you not just do what you're doing that you've got working and make sure to apply it every time you write a cell that's in the 1st, 2nd or 4th column?

Comment: thanks buddy. easyxf helped me do that so easily

Comment: Hi, that protection worked on MS Excel but when opening that file via Mac's Numbers or Google Sheet, protection gets revoked automatically